# Changing a button using ajax which runs a php code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am new to JQuery AJAX and i need help with my code. What i want is when i click the add button it will change to delete button. but what happens in my code is that it changes to delete button but when i click delete button, it does not change back to add button. i want it to look like some sort of toggle. here's my html code with javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#add_button').click(function(){
            var temp = $('#add_button').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax_test.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {add_button: temp},
                success: function(data){
                    $('div').html(data);
                }
            });
        });

        $('#delete_button').click(function(){
            var temp = $('#delete_button').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax_test.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {delete_button: temp},
                success: function(data){
                    $('div').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <button id="add_button" name="add" value="testing">Add</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

and here's my php code:

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST["add_button"])){

    echo "<button id='delete_button' name='delete' value='testing'>Delete</button>";

}


if(isset($_POST["delete_button"])){

    echo "<button id='add_button' name='add' value='testing'>Add</button>";

}


?>
```

please help. thanks

Comment: try changing the value for the each button uniquely..

Comment: Why dont you hide button the button clicked and show other one

Comment: still doesn't work. :(

Comment: but i need to run some other codes in the php file.

Comment: That's because your `click` listener isn't assigned to newly added `#delete_button`, you should attach listener to `div` using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('div').on('click', '#add_button', function(){
            var temp = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax_test.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {add_button: temp},
                success: function(data){
                    $('div').html(data);
                }
            });
        });

        $('div').on('click', '#delete_button', function(){
            var temp = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax_test.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {delete_button: temp},
                success: function(data){
                    $('div').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Your code won't work on dynamically added elements, while above code works.

Read http://api.jquery.com/on/ for more informations.

Comment: Search for "live event in jquery", if you work with dynamically added elements, you shouldn't directly attach listener to the id/class of the element. Attach to higher hierarchy element (e.g. `document`, or its direct parent) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try hiding the button clicked and show other button something like

```
  $('#add_button').click(function(){
            var temp = $('#add_button').val();            
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax_test.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {add_button: temp},
                success: function(data){
                    $('div').html(data);
                    $('#add_button').hide();
                    $('#delete_button').show();

                }
            });
        });

        $('#delete_button').click(function(){
            var temp = $('#delete_button').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax_test.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {delete_button: temp},
                success: function(data){
                    $('div').html(data);
                    $('#delete_button').hide();
                    $('#add_button').show();
                }
            });
        });
```

Or you can use jquery toggle 
$( "#add_button").toggle()

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: thanks but i need to run the php code. i'll be running database query in the php code soon.

Comment: How is running query affecting visibility of button?

Comment: if add button is clicked, run some database query on the php file then change it to delete button. and when delete button is clicked, vice versa

Comment: so whats the problem in it, code is hiding button on ajax success , meaning when you get success response from server

Answer (score 1):

Your solution wasn't working, because delete button event handler was being attached to DOM before the DOM element(delete button) was initialised.

So, one event for both buttons would be enough:

```
$('button').click(function(){
        var button = $(this); 
        if(button.data('type') == 'add') {    
            var postData =  {add_button: button.val()};
        } else {
            var postData =  {delete_button: button.val()};
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax_test.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            success: function(data){
                $('div').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <button data-type="add" name="add" value="testing">Add</button>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST["add_button"])){

    echo "<button data-type='delete' name='delete' value='testing'>Delete</button>";

}


if(isset($_POST["delete_button"])){

    echo "<button data-type='add' name='add' value='testing'>Add</button>";

}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

Give a class name to button:

```
<button id="add_button" class="btnOp" name="add" value="testing">Add</button>
```

Then you can add a js click event to that classname and change its data accordingly:

```
$('.btnOp').on('click',function()
{
    var text=$(this).text();
    if(text==="Add")
    {
         var temp = $('#add_button').val();
         $.ajax({
                url: "ajax_test.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {add_button: temp},
                success: function(data){
                    $('div').html(data);
                    $('.btnOp').val('testing');
                }
         });
     }
     else
     { 
         var temp = $('#delete_button').val();
         $.ajax({
                url: "ajax_test.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {delete_button: temp},
                success: function(data){
                    $('div').html(data);
                    $('.btnOp').val('testing');
                }
         });
      }
});
```

**This will help you to change button values and functionality on success of ajax and acts like kind of toggle**

Comment: `$('div').html(data);` replaces all contents in div, so your `click` listener won't work.

Comment: @Aprian what should i do then?

Comment: Try keeping that button outside the div!!